# Use of UNION enables more powerful SQL constructions

Tags: sql, sql-server, calendar, union

I think it a shame that an OP deleted this question, poorly worded and phrased as it was; It provides an opportunity to demonstrate the use of the **UNION** operation in SQL to dynamically construct relations needed to perform operations efficiently:
Original post from (I will attribute source if OP comments below requesting it):

> i have two tables called tblBooking and tblRoom
>   tblBooking has an ID, Day, RoomID;
>   tblRoom has an ID, Description
>
> i need to create a query that shows which rooms arent in use on
>   certain days, ie 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
>
> how can i do it using a union query? i have tried all different
>   combinations, but cant get anything to work, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008+, you can also use table-value constructors:

```
SELECT Day, RoomID
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) as Days(Day) 
CROSS JOIN tblRoom
EXCEPT
SELECT Day, RoomID FROM tblBooking
ORDER BY RoomID, Day
```

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/row-value-constructor-as-derived-table.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx

Comment: A UNION without the `union` key-word! I keep forgetting this construct exists after so many years of writing them the other way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, with a union used to create the calendar table **Days**:

```
select Day, Room ID
from (
  select Day=1 union select Day=2 union select Day=3 union select Day=4 union
  select Day=5 union select Day=6 union select Day=7
) Days
cross join tblRoom

except

select Day, RoomID from tblBooking

order by RoomID, Day
```

Answer (score 1):

here's another way without using `UNION`

```
WITH NumberSequence
AS
(
    SELECT 1 Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1 FROM NumberSequence WHERE Number < 7
)
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    NumberSequence a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT RoomID FROM TableName) b
        LEFT JOIN TableName c
          ON c.Day = a.Number AND c.RoomID = b.RoomID
WHERE   c.RoomID IS NULL
ORDER   BY a.Number, c.RoomID, c.Day
OPTION (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad3dc/14)

Comment: +1: Your `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL` is useful when **EXCEPT** is unavailable; I have used it myself in the past. `NumberSequence` works nicely for this particular example, but is specialized to numeric-only constructed tables; in more general cases UNION is (I believe) still needed to construct the cross join.

Comment: Too many results. `CROSS JOIN TableName b` should be a cross join to the distinct RoomIDs in the table, or be a different table. The code implies `TableName b` and `TableName c` are one and the same

Comment: @PieterGeerkens what do you mean by numeric only? it can also generate date, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12474

Comment: @JW웃L Ah! How many built in ...Sequences are there? Are there others besides NumberSequence and DateTimeSequence?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens actually it is not about sequences. `Common Table Expression` is for recursive query.